# Difference in Hive query execution via Beeline & Hortonworks ODBC Driver

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have two tables in Hive.

```
CREATE TABLE Target_table(
col_1 timestamp,
col_2 int,
col_3 int) CLUSTERED BY (col_1) INTO 50 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC 
TBLPROPERTIES('transactional'='true')

CREATE TABLE Source_table(
col_1 timestamp,
col_2 int)
```

I am trying to execute this query

```
INSERT INTO Target_table (col_1, col_2) 
SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM Source_table;
```

Query runs successfully in Beeline.

Same query fails when executed via Hortonworks ODBC Driver with the error

```
ERROR [HY000] [Hortonworks][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error 
thrown in server while executing query. 
Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: 
SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:18 Cannot insert into target table 
because column number/types are different 'Targer': Table insclause-0 has 3 
columns, but query has 2 columns.
```

Looks like Hive is completely ignoring the column list in the Insert clause.

Other Details

```
Cluster: Azure HDInsight Cluster
Hortonworkds Data Platform: HDP-2.6.2.25
OS: Windows 10
Language: C#
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query as a workaround.

```
INSERT INTO Target_table(col_1, col_2, col_3) SELECT col_1, col_2,int(null) col_3 FROM Source_table;
```